# Nested for loops and the placement of variables

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am currently attempting to solve a problem where I try to find the smallest triangular sum of terms in a triangular array. (The array I am currently using is a 3x3 triangular array)

```
  colAmt =1;
  int tempCol = rows;
  int tempSum=0;
  rows = 3;

  for(int t=0;t<rows;t++)
  {

      for(int col = 0; col<colAmt; col++)
      {
          tempCol=0;
          tempSum =0;

          for(int m=t;m<rows;m++)
          {
              System.out.println(m+", "+tempCol);
              tempSum = tempSum + sumTriangle[m][tempCol];

                      tempCol++;
                      if(tempSum<triSum)
                      {
                          triSum = tempSum;
                      }
          }
      }
      colAmt++;
  }
```

When I execute the program, the program prints out:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)
(2, 0)
(2, 0)
```

When it should be printing:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

I'm pretty sure It's a problem with the way I'm handling the tempCol variable, but I'm not sure how to fix it. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are the values in sumTriangle? What do you mean by triangle sum?

Comment: ... and why should a 3x3 triangular array give 10 results?

Comment: Neither of those things are relevant to the question I asked, so I didn't include them. My question was simply on the discrepancy between the indexes in my loops.

Comment: And the results printed here are the indexes as printed by the print statement in the code. There are only 6 elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the numbers you want by replacing

```
tempCol=0;
```

with

```
tempCol=col;
```